# On constructing a group containing each subgroup once up to isomorphism

Tags: group-theory

Let $\mathfrak{G}$ be the free product of all finite (say) groups. Then for every subgroup $K$ (finite or not), identify it with each subgroup of $\mathfrak{G}$ isomorphic to $K$ to obtain a quotient group $\mathfrak{G}_1$. Repeat.

My questions are:

1. Does this process "terminate" in any meaningful way? For example, after $n$ steps at some group $\mathfrak{G}_n$, or does the limit $\mathfrak{G}_{\infty}$ make sense?
2. If this process does "terminate", what group does it terminate at? In particular, does it terminate at the group $C_2\times C_3\times C_5\times\cdots \times C_p\times\cdots$? (The direct product of cyclic groups of prime order.)

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the definition of $\mathfrak{G}_1$. Do you mean $\mathfrak{G}_1 = \mathfrak{G}/N_K$, where $N_K$ is the subgroup generated by all subgroups of $\mathfrak{G}$ that are isomorphic to $K$?

Comment: No - it's meant to mimick free product with amalgamation. Also, it's for *all* isomorphism classes of subgroups, not just a single one. So define $N_{(K, \phi)}=\langle\langle \{k^{-1}\phi(k)\mid k\in K\}\rangle\rangle$ where $\phi$ is some isomorphism between subgroups and $\langle\langle S\rangle\rangle$ denotes the normal closure of the set $S$. Then $N_K:=\langle N_{(K, \phi)}\mid \phi \text{ a subgroup isomorphism}\rangle$, and then $N=\prod_{K<\mathfrak{G}} N_K$. Then $\mathfrak{G}_1=\mathfrak{G}/N$. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes it makes sense now! But perhaps the outcome depends on what order you process the subgroups $K$? And there are uncountably many such $K$.